# Pegar valores ListView - GetElementByID

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp

Boa noite!
Tenho uma listView e estou exibindo os valores dentro de Span's, gostaria de pegar o valor do span ao clicar mas como os Span's tem o mesmo ID acabo pegando sempre o mesmo valor.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como contornar isso?

```
<script>

      function controle(e) {

          var outros = document.getElementById('ooooo').textContent;

          alert(outros);






      }

  </script>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">


<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table style="" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>Nenhum dado foi retornado.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>



<ItemTemplate>



      <span class='fc-event' ID="ooooo" onclick="controle()"><%# Eval("Expr1") %></span>  

</ItemTemplate>



<LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server">
        <tr runat="server">
            <td runat="server">
                <table runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style="" border="0">

                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server">
            <td runat="server" style="">
                <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager1" PageSize="25">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                        <asp:NumericPagerField></asp:NumericPagerField>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>

                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<SelectedItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>

    </tr>
</SelectedItemTemplate>
```

```
        </div>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:COEX_RPBConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT PROJETO + ' - ' + TITULO AS Expr1 FROM tbl_obras_projetos_final WHERE (STATUS_USUARIO = 'Execução')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: porque não utilizou o controler para fazer isso?

Comment: Pq eu preciso listar todos os valores, dai eu pego o dado ao clicar e ploto em um mapa.
Por isso a necessidade de listar todos os dados.

Comment: eu disse o seguinte! porque não utilizou o componente?

Comment: Desculpa a minha ignorância, mas pode enviar uma documentação de apoio ou um exemplo? Eu realmente sou Noob

Comment: `<span class='fc-event' ID="ooooo" onclick="controle()"><%# Eval("Expr1") %></span>` o problema é aqui ?

Comment: Exato. Ele exibe mais de 200 resultados mas ao clicar em um deles eu sempre pego o valor do primeiro usando a função controle()

Comment: Posso ver seu javascript controle() ?

Comment: <script>

      function controle(e) {

          var outros = document.getElementById('ooooo').textContent;

          alert(outros);






      }

  </script>

Answer (score 0):

Configure assim?

```js
function controle(obj) 
{
 var outros = obj.textContent;
 alert(outros);
}
```

```html
<label onclick="controle(this);">Número 1</label><br /><br />
<label onclick="controle(this);">Número 2</label><br /><br />
<label onclick="controle(this);">Número 3</label><br />
```

e naquele `label`:

```
<span class='fc-event' ID="ooooo" onclick="controle(this)">
    <%# Eval("Expr1") %>
</span>
```

**ou**

```js
function controle(value) {
  alert(value);
}
```

```html
<label onclick="controle('Número 1')"> Número 1</label>
<br /><br />
<label onclick="controle('Número 2')"> Número 2</label>
<br /><br />
<label onclick="controle('Número 3')"> Número 3</label><br />
```

```
<span class='fc-event' ID="ooooo" onclick="controle('<%# Eval("Expr1") %>')">
    <%# Eval("Expr1") %>
</span>
```

Comment: Virgílio Novic daqui a 30 eu testo e te retorno.

Comment: Estou mando o email agora .  Deu certo o código que você enviou.

Comment: @PedroVanderlanSantana exclui esses comentários ok!

Comment: E se eu quiser trocar a cor do elemento que eu cliquei?
Antes eu usava document.getElementByID()

Comment: Mandei os e-mails infelizmente enviei sem o assunto.